# CakePHP set XML view encoding to UCS2

Tags: xml, cakephp, encoding, ucs2

I need to set the encoding of my XML view to UCS2.
I have tried to add the following to the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UCS-2"?>
```

and

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UCS-2'); ?>
```

I have also tried to put this in the controller of the view:

```
$this->header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UCS-2');
```

But each time when I open the xml view in the browser, save it to my desktop and open it with Notepad++ to check the file encoding it is set to UTF-8 without BOM.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to set the encoding for the specific XML view. TIA

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**The encoding is being read**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.3/lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php#L207) from the `App.encoding` [**configuration option**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration), so what you could do is change it accordingly to `UCS-2` in the specific action that generates the XML document.

Additionally you'll probably also have to change [**the charset of the response**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse::charset), as it's initially being set in the `CakeResponse` constructor.

```php
public function xyzAction() {
    Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UCS-2');
    $this->response->charset('UCS-2');

    // ...

    $this->set('_serialize', /* ... */);

    // ...
}
```

This should not only change the `encoding` attribute in the XML document, but also the `charset` of the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: your answer got me half way there, indeed I had to use the Configure::write function and set the charset of the response, but this resulted in Chinese letters. In addition I had to use iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE', "[THE STRING"]") to get english encoded output. Thanks for your help.